# How do I create an image on the cli of a certain size and color?

Tags: imagemagick

I want to create a jpg or png image of say 127x67 of colour green.  How do I do this using the command line, with something like convert.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With ImageMagick, you would use the `CANVAS:`, or `XC:` protocol.

```
convert -size 127x67 xc:green output.jpg
```

[image: Create an image of a certain size]

Other great examples [Canvas Creation](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/canvas/) & [Color Names](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color.php).

Comment: Note that "green" in ImageMagick is actually 50% green.  Saturated 100% green is called "lime" or "green1".

Comment: That's right @GlennRanders-Pehrson ! J0hnG4lt, see [List of Color Names](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/color.php#color_names) for additional color alternatives, and **hsl** color functions.